# Remotely controlling computer casting video to a dumb TV with Chromecast

Tags: chrome, streaming, video-player, chromecast

I have videos locally stored on a computer (Mac), and if I load them up in Chrome, I can cast to a Chromecast plugged into a dumb (non-Android) TV.  So far, so good.

However, the TV is located in a different room, which means I need to run over to the casting computer to start/pause/stop the video stream.  Is there any way I can remotely control the stream, either in Chrome or via some other Chromecast-compatible app?

Answer (score 1):

VLC can Chromecast. It also has an iPhone remote app [so likely an equivalent for Android] meaning you could control it entirely from your phone.

It's apparently on the Playback menu > Renderer >
I don't have one to test, picture from [HelloTech - How to Cast VLC to Chromecast](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-cast-vlc-to-chromecast)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I tried this out, but while I can get VLC to cast and VLC Mobile Remote https://vlcmobileremote.com/ to detect my computer, the app says "VLC is not running" :/